# How to ignore <br /> if <cfoutput> returns nothing?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a `<cfoutput>` placing address variables in a table. The problem I have is these variables are sometimes null, but because of the line breaks they still take up space in the table.

```
   <td>  
    <cfoutput>
       #getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine1#<br />
       #getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine2#<br />
       #getMeeting.meetingDemographicsCity#
    </cfoutput>
   </td>
```

**How can I get the browser to ignore the `<br />` tags if the variable is null?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a print line function using `cffunction` and use `cfif` to check for the length of the value being over 0. i.e.

Be sure you actually mean null too, see http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1654-Learning-ColdFusion-9-IsNull-And-Working-With-NULL-Values.htm

**Examples**

```
<cffunction name="PrintLine" returntype="void">
  <cfargument name="Value" />
  <cfif len(arguments.Value) GT 0>
    <cfoutput>#arguments.Value#<br /></cfoutput>
  </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

or to return from the function: -

```
<cffunction name="PrintLine2" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="Value" />
  <cfset var foo = "" />
  <cfif len(trim(arguments.Value)) GT 0>
    <cfset foo = arguments.Value & "</br />" />
  </cfif>
  <cfreturn foo />
</cffunction>
```

Optionally add your return type/hint/required attributes as needed

**Documentation**

See http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_21.html

and

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_i_01.html

You can then just do: -

```
<td>  
  <cfoutput>
   #PrintLine(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine1)#
   #PrintLine(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine2)#
   #getMeeting.meetingDemographicsCity#
  </cfoutput>
</td>
```

Comment: It is not really good practice to output text from inside a function. A different way to handle this might be by returning the string (with the <br /> appended to it) if it has a length or an empty string if it does not. Also, in a case like this, it might be best to do the check using len( trim() ) rather than just len().

Comment: I don't agree with @ScottStroz.  A function is supposed to do something.  It doesn't necesarily have to return anything.  I would simply add 'returntype="void"' to the cffunction tag.

Comment: Both scenarios are included above for the sake of argument - included return type, although I was leaving the optional attributes out and provided additional reading to cover this.

Comment: I would say that a function that outputs directly AND returns a value is bad practice, but a return void function is common in most languages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type

Comment: I never said a function HAS to return anything, I said it is not good practice to use <cfoutput> (to output text, etc to the buffer) inside of a function - big difference. A function is supposed to do something - but that something should not include outputting anything to the buffer - 'either return a value that can be output to the buffer to make it into a custom tag' is a rule of thumb I use when coding.

Comment: @ScottStroz I can't find anything that says output to the buffer from a function is bad practice.  In fact, from what I can see it looks common place with void functions.  I'm happy to be wrong if I am but I don't see it in my research.  Personally I don't do it either, I always return the output, but I can't find it as a "bad practice" anywhere.  Am I looking in the wrong places?

Comment: @ScottStroz why edit to change this `<cfset foo = "#arguments.Value#</br />" />`? The updated way, while cleaner looking, requires string concatenation, doesn't it?

Comment: Let me amend my statement - it may not be an 'official' best practice, but I feel using <cfoutput> in a function to output text, etc to the buffer is not a good idea - I would even go so far as saying it is a bad idea. I have NEVER written a UDF that directly outputs to the buffer. I either return values to be output, or, if I can't do that (for whatever reason), I turn it in to a custom tag.

Comment: @MattBusche Your question answered itself. It is cleaner :D

Comment: Thinking about this more...I tend to think of everything from an MVC standpoint. I prefer to have functions I write be used anywhere in the stack. Outputting text to the buffer from inside the function makes it possible to ONLY use this function in the View - as such, the way it was originally written, might be better suited to a custom tag rather than a function.

Comment: Ok so it's 'personal preference' and not 'bad practice'.  I don't disagree, in fact, I almost voted your comment up before I really thought about it.  People doing things differently isn't bad practice, it's just different practice. My $.02 on the concatenation... `<cfset foo = arguments.Value & "</br />" />` is cleaner to some,  `<cfset foo = "#arguments.Value#</br />" />` is cleaner to others.  For longer strings with lots of variables, I'd probably use the original code. `<cfset foo = "#arguments.Value#</br />" />` is faster but you'd have to run it 100k times to see it. :p

Comment: It has been my experience that code similar to `<cfset foo = "#arguments.value#<br />" />` tends to lead (new) developers to consistently overuse `##` in CFML. That is one of my biggest pet peeves in CFML, and rarely, if ever, will I use syntax like that.

Comment: Have to agree with the overuse of #s. I even wrote an tutorial long ago on setting Dreamweaver code colors to easily identify unneeded pound signs.

Comment: @chrisw69 - Do not forgot to localize the function variables in `PrintLine2`.

Comment: Continuing this healthy exchange of opinions, I see functions simply as one of the available methods to re-use code.  I also tend see every situation as being different.  The question looks like a situation applicable to only one page so a udf on that page only looks appropriate.  Also, simply outputting the variable rather creating a new one which still gets outputted looks to be the most efficient way to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <cfoutput>
    <cfif len(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine1) gt 0 >
           #getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine1#
    </cfif>
    <cfif len(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine2) gt 0 >
           <br />#getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine2#
    </cfif>
    <cfif len(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsCity) gt 0 >
            <cfif len(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine1) gt 0 or  len(getMeeting.meetingDemographicsAddressLine2) gt 0>
                 <br />#getMeeting.meetingDemographicsCity#
            <cfelse>
                #getMeeting.meetingDemographicsCity#
            </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: There is no need to have the second IF statement for the City since you have the <br /> before the strings for each part of the address adn you have already checked for the existence of address1 and address2.